# Java Triple DES algorithm Padding modes

Tags: java, encryption, tripledes

I need to know what are the padding modes applicable to Triple DES algorithm , 
Is AI_PKCS_PADDING a padding mode applicable to Triple DES ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Java Cipher API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html):

```
Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard Cipher transformations with the keysizes in parentheses: 


    AES/CBC/NoPadding (128)
    AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (128)
    AES/ECB/NoPadding (128)
    AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (128)
    DES/CBC/NoPadding (56)
    DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (56)
    DES/ECB/NoPadding (56)
    DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (56)
    DESede/CBC/NoPadding (168)
    DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding (168)
    DESede/ECB/NoPadding (168)
    DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding (168)
    RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding (1024, 2048)
    RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding (1024, 2048)
    RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding (1024, 2048)
```

Hence it should support `PKCS5Padding`

Comment: Tanx for response, but could you please say what is deference of AES and DES and DESede, Actually I want to send encrypted data to a device which is support standard DES algorithm and I dont know which mode I should use which matches the Standard algorithm implementation (CBC mode)

Comment: Regarding which algorithm to use, regular DES is only 56 bit key, so DESede (3DES) should be used over that. AES is a different algoritm and if your device doesnt support that you should not use it :) Regarding modes, CBC mode is the be perfeered over ECB since ECB is not safe. Good description about the different modes can be found at the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation)

Comment: Which is the default mode?

Answer (score 1):

> Triple DES algorithm Padding modes (...)  I dont know which mode I should use (...)

- Padding in general: [Using Padding in Encryption](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptopad.html)
- Common modes: [Block cipher mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation)

DES Modes of Operation (Triple DES is based on DES):

- ECB
- CBC
- CFB
- OFB

> what is deference of AES and DES and DESede

- [AES](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)
- [DES](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)
- [Triple DES (DESede)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES)